# Javascript returning a string as a regex for jquery validate add method

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-validate

I have this jquery validate add method below with a specific regex.

What I want is to create a method that returns the regex, like in my second example, but the second example doesn't work. I get some error that says 'Object doesn't support property or method 'test'

```js
if (scope.countryCode == "DE") {
  $.validator.addMethod('PostalCodeError',
    function(value) {
      return /^(?!01000|99999)(0[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4})$/.test(value);
    }, 'Please enter a valid German postal code.');

  $("#PostalCode").rules("add", {
    PostalCodeError: true
  });
}
```

I want something like this below

```js
$.validator.addMethod('PostalCodeError',
  function(value) {
    return GetCountryRegex().test(value);
  }, 'Please enter a valid postal code.');

$("#PostalCode").rules("add", {
  PostalCodeError: true
});


function GetCountryRegex() {
  if (scope.countryCode == "DE") {
    return '/^(?!01000|99999)(0[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4})$/';
  }
  if (scope.countryCode == "AT") {
    return '/^\\d{4}$/';
  }
}
```

Comment: note that `/regexp/` and `'/regexp/'` are 2 different things (the second is a string). Try with `return new RegExp('regexp');`

Comment: I removed the Code Snippets.  They are completely pointless if you don't include the proper HTML/CSS/JavaScript/plugins to make a live demo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, in `GetCountryRegex` you're not actually returning RegEx, your returning strings.

Use [`new RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) on the returned value to convert the strings to RegExp:

```
function GetCountryRegex() {
  if (scope.countryCode == "DE") {
    return '/^(?!01000|99999)(0[1-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4})$/';
  }
  if (scope.countryCode == "AT") {
    return '/^\\d{4}$/';
  }
}

var regExp = new RegExp(GetCountryRegex());
regExp.test(...);
```